# Get id with jQuery of element added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a modal to submit a form. Once the modal closes, I wish to update the table on the page to reflect the changes in the database. For this purpose I use jQuery. It is working quite well. Well, except for one thing.

I can update an existing line. I can create a new line. But I can't update one that I just created. I use this function to monitor the modal:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalResourceTypeEditNew', function(){
    var id = $('#ModalResourceTypeId').val();
    if(id != "" && id != 0)
    {
        var data = {
            Id: id
        };

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Administration/ResourceType",
            data: data,
            success: function(content){

                if($('#ResourceType' + id).length)
                {                    
                    updateResourceTypeRow(content, ("#ResourceType" + id));
                }
                else
                {
                    newResourceTypeRow(content, ("#ResourceType" + id));
                }

            },
            error: function(e) {}
        })
    }
})
```

Both the update and new functions work as they should, but content created by the `newResourceTypeRow` is not registered by the `$(#id)` thing. It's as if it can't register it because it has been added since the page was loaded.

I read about the `.on()` function to handle this, but I can not seem to use that at my AJAX `success:` clause. Any suggestions as to how I should go about this?

Comment: Hi! So who's responsible for setting the `$('#ModalResourceTypeId')` value in the first place? Where/how do you put your ids in there?

Comment: Please post the code for the `updateResourceTypeRow` and `newResourceTypeRow` functions.